# Is my raspberry pi 4 broken?

Tags: sd-card, power

I'm using raspberry pi 4 to operate a servo motor and it was working appropriately yesterday.
Today, I found the pi is getting too hot to hold and I cannot ssh to the pi. Because I cannot shutdown it, so I detached USB type-C power cable and all the other cable including micro-SD card.

I tried connecting things again, but the display isn't shown to my monitor. I tried connecting the micro-SD card to another desktop PC but it isn't detected by machine and even it gets too hot to touch.

I tried another micro-SD card. I have written raspbian OS into it. Inserted it into the Pi and connected power cable and microHDMI, then immediately they get very hot and the display isn't still shown.

Is there anything I can still try? How can I confirm my Pi got completely broken?

Comment: Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question it is broken. From your description you connect a motor(s) directly to its port pins. When one or more of the motor coils was switched off it generate a transient that destroyed the Pi Port. This coupled with the fact that the motor overloaded the port pins causing them to get warm and more susceptible to transients. These transient was created each time a coil was turned off. If the motor was powered from 5V the same scenario could occur.

Never connect anything inductive to a Pi Port Pin unless it is specifically designed to be connected that way. Rule #1 A Power Supply the Pie Is NOT.